# Get the closest element to a SVG node using Jquery closest() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var svg = d3.select("svg");

    svg.append("circle")
            .attr("class","cursor")
            .attr("r", 8)
            .attr("cx", 100)
            .attr("cy", 100)
            .on("click", test);

    function test(d)
    {
        f = d3.select(this);

        console.log($(f).closest('svg').css('border-color','red'));


    }

});
```

I noticed that it doesn't work. But if I execute the same function on a non SVG element (regular html element like div or canvas...) it does what it is supposed to do.
I first thought that the problem was the d3 selection. I then parsed the element directly with the class attribute like:

```
console.log($('.cursor').closest('svg').css('border-color','red'));
```

Without success.
Is there a way to make the jquery closest() function work with element inside SVG tag ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping a d3 selection in `$` is invalid. Use `$(this)` instead of `$(f)`. The `this` keyword in the click handler is set to the clicked DOM element, which is what you need.